# Unable to change state on key press in TextInput component (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a simple typing test that does two things:

1. Keep a count of the words a user types in the text input
2. Clear the text input when a user presses on Return or the space key

I have a function in the onKeyPress prop that updates both states whenever the user presses the space key but only the word count is being incremented. On the console, it looks like the key presses are being registered but the text state isn't updating.

Any help would be appreciated! Here's what I have:

**State**

```
state = {
  text: "",
  words: 0
};
```

**Update Text Input**

```
updateInput(event) {
  this.setState({
    text: event.nativeEvent.text
  });
}
```

**TextInput Component**

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.text}
  onChange={this.updateInput.bind(this)}
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.key === " ") {
      this.setState({
        text: "",
        words: this.state.words + 1
      });
      console.log(this.state.text);
      console.log("onKeyPress worked!");
      console.log(
        "there are a total of " + this.state.words + " words!"
      );
    }
  }}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  autoFocus={true}
  autoCorrect={false}
  autoCompleteType={false}
  allowFontScaling={true}
  keyboardType="default"
  keyboardAppearance="dark"
  onSubmitEditing={event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      text: "",
      words: this.state.words + 1
    });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onKeyPress` gets fired before `onChange` any state changes you made in `onKeyPress` gets overwritten by `onChange`. Add a boolean value to your state which will check if the state should reset.

```
state = {
  text: '',
  words: 0,
  reset: false,
};

updateInput(event) {

  if (this.state.reset) {

    this.setState({
      reset: false,
    });

    return;
  }
  this.setState({
    text: event.nativeEvent.text,
  });
}

<TextInput
  value={this.state.text}
  onChange={this.updateInput.bind(this)}
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.key === ' ') {
      this.setState({
        text: '',
        words: this.state.words + 1,
        reset: true,
      });
      console.log(this.state.text);
      console.log('onKeyPress worked!');
      console.log(
        'there are a total of ' + this.state.words + ' words!'
      );
    }
  }}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  autoFocus={true}
  autoCorrect={false}
  autoCompleteType={false}
  allowFontScaling={true}
  keyboardType="default"
  keyboardAppearance="dark"
  onSubmitEditing={event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      text: '',
      words: this.state.words + 1,
    });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Worked perfectly! I was losing my hair, haha. One small thing I noticed was that if I press the "spacebar" too quickly, the event doesn't register so multiple words string together before the input clears. This is mostly happening on my device and very seldom on the simulator. Any way to optimize how quickly the spacebar registers?